# Change URL with PHP variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, path

I have this path: myweb.com/aaa/bbb/value

I want to make it so that users will not see the path and in its place use PHP variables, like:

```
//directories
$1 = 'dir1';
$2 = 'dir2';
$3 = 'dir3';
$4 = 'dir4';

//values
$value1 = '';
$value2 = '';

myweb.com/$1/$2/$value1
myweb.com/$3/$4/$value2
```

But always using the same path.

Comment: Whose "people" you're referring to? Are you leaking your source code to the "view"? :P

Comment: you can use session to pass information between pages.

Comment: Chay22, anybody can see my path, SEO problem, you know. I would like the path was always the same and create false paths.

Answer (score 0):

Right now i can think of following solutions:
1) Use session
Store all values in session and you can get them wherever you need.

2) Or you can encrpt and pass over the url. like below:

```
$1 = urlencode('dir1');
//values
$value1 = urlencode('dir1');    
myweb.com/$1/$value1
```

And you can decode the values using [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)